# How to write output with fout function in properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read and write a file with python file system but I'm having some problems. I believe that the reading/opening function is correct but the writing one is giving me a hard time.

I'm doing it inside a function that inverts a dictionary and I want it to read the dictionary from a text file instead of doing it inside the code, here's how I called it(not beautifully but works):

```
d = fin = open('dict.txt')
```

However, when it comes to writing the inverted dictionary to a file I'm failing miserably. The function call that prints the inverted dict is `invert_dict(d)` so I thought that I should try to write it like this:

```
invert_dict(d) = fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

Which is clearly wrong but that's what I got from reading a book. Here's my raw invert dictionary function :

```
def invert_dict(d):
    print(' the dictionary is \n' , d)
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        for i in val:
            if i not in inverse:
                inverse[i] = [key]
            else:
                inverse[i].append(key)
    return inverse
d={'vowels':['a','e','i','o','u'], 'letters':['a','b','c','d']}
print(invert_dict(d))
```

How should I improve my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want it to be properly, first use 'with open' construct (https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python); also try to separate functionality - avoid creating superclass or supermethod in this case that does everything

Comment: @Drako Sweet, so instead of using the ugly d = fin = open('dict.txt') I can use with open(“dict.txt”) as file:? Appreciate it!
Regarding writing my output in a text file, thoughts? :)

Comment: @Bruno see my edit?

Comment: @U9-Forward Yes sir, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty good, just using `items` to loop is better, and also `setdefault` is easier:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    print(' the dictionary is \n' , d)
    inverse = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        for i in v:
            inverse.setdefault(i,[]).append(k)
    return inverse
```

**edit:**

Misunderstood before, so you should use:

```
import json
d = fin = json.loads(open('dict.txt'))
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(invert_dict(d))
```

Comment: Thanks! Regarding writing the inverted dictionary though, thoughts? :)

Comment: @Bruno I think this is the best as it gets :-) remember to accept and up-vote if it is good :-)

Comment: Again, appreciate your comment regarding this function, it took me a while to do it! However, maybe I didn't make myself clear, my issue is not with this function per se. I wanna change it through fin and fout function, which is the subject that I'm studying at the moment

Comment: Now I got it, thanks! So every time that I'm exchanging data I should import json and then carry on from there. Appreciate a lot your time, now I can carry on with my studies, thank you very much!